# Calling a method multiple times with different values

Tags: java

I'm doing some code to control a locker system, in which I want to define which locker will be opened setting values to `X` and `Y` arguments (Imagining that the lockers are arranged as a `matrix X,Y`). I've tested the method with a single `(X,Y)` values and it works fine, but when I tried to use new ones it actually updated the values. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm actually new to java. The code is something like that. It is the first time I'm posting here, so sorry if I did some mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainApp extends Application{
...
            LockerControl(3, 0);
            LockerControl(1, 1);
}

  private void LockerControl(int X,int Y) throws Exception {
            LockerControl locker = new LockerControl(); 
            locker.count(X, Y);
            Thread.sleep(10000);   
            locker.reset();
    }

public class LockerControl {

    int counter;
    boolean flagSensor;

    public void count(int X, int Y) throws Exception{

        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        final GpioPinDigitalOutput myLed[] = {
            gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_04, "LED_1", PinState.LOW),
            gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_05, "LED_2", PinState.LOW),
            gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_06, "LED_3", PinState.LOW)};
        PCA9685GpioTester pca9685Gpio = new PCA9685GpioTester(); 
        GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02);

        myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
            @Override
            public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(
                    GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
                if (event.getState().isHigh()) {
                    if (!flagSensor) {
                        myButton.addTrigger(new GpioPulseStateTrigger(myLed[1], 1000));
                        ++counter;
                        if (counter == X+1) {
                            flagSensor = true;
                            try {
                                pca9685Gpio.on(X, Y); 
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(LockerControl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        myButton.addTrigger(new GpioPulseStateTrigger(myLed[2], 1000));
                        --counter;
                        if (counter == 0 && flagSensor) {
                            try {
                                pca9685Gpio.off(X, Y);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(LockerControl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    myButton.addTrigger(new GpioSetStateTrigger(myLed[0], PinState.LOW));
                    myButton.addTrigger(new GpioSetStateTrigger(myLed[1], PinState.LOW));
                    myButton.addTrigger(new GpioSetStateTrigger(myLed[2], PinState.LOW));                   
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void reset() {
        counter = 0;
        flagSensor = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using a `static int` for `counter` and a `static boolean` for `flagSensor` but you've got multiple instances of `LockerControl`. Static variables are common to all instances of a class (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)). You can fix this by removing the static modifier.

Note that if it is possible for different threads to modify the individual `LockerControl` instances, look into [concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and/or [Atomic Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), [Atomic Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) classes.

Comment: I removed the static from int and counter, but its still repeating the first parameters (in the example the 2,1). It's possible in Java to call, for example, LockerControl(X,Y) multiple times only changing the (X,Y) values?

Comment: What purpose does `try {Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (InterruptedException ex)` serve and why don't you log anything in the catch?

Comment: I intended to do a timer of 10 s between the first and the second call of LockerControl(X,Y). Probably i could change it just for Thread.sleep(10000) instead.

Comment: It's hard to tell what else might be the cause but another place to look is the `PCA9685GpioTester` class, for the same problem as mentioned in my answer.